# Retrieve all product IDs associated with a Catalog Price Rule in Magento

Tags: magento

I need a way to retrieve product IDs associated with a Catalog Price Rule promotion (ex. 50% the price of all items in the BICYCLES category).  I'd like to do this without having to iterate through the entire product database.

I know there is a function called `getRuleProductIds($ruleID)`, which should return an array of product IDs by rule ID, but I have no idea where to use it, which collection to associate it with, etc.

I have the following code in a `products_in_promotion.phtml` template:

```
<?php 
  $rules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule');
  $collection = $rules->getCollection();
  $sale_items = $collection->getRuleProductIds(1); # ??????? this throws an error
?>
```

`$collection` properly stores an array of all the Catalog Price rules, but that's as close as I can get.  No product list is in sight.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to get it as a collection.  Just load the rule that you want and use `getMatchingProductIds` as found in `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule` (aka `catalogrule/rule`).

```
$catalog_rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(1);  // Rule ID
$skus = $catalog_rule->getMatchingProductIds();

var_dump($skus);
```

hth

Comment: Is there a way to "load" a rule by using its name and not ID?

Comment: $catalog_rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load('Your rule name','name');   (see: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11623/how-to-load-a-catalog-price-rule-by-name)

Comment: @seanbreeden This is not working in Magento 1.4.1.1 Do we have any alternative for this?

Comment: @Muk What are you trying exactly and I'll check it out

Comment: @seanbreeden Actually I am developing a module to check if a product has catalog price rule applied then I have to move that product to a specific category. And once the rule expire or deactivate the product should be removed from that category. (Even if the product comes under multiple catalog price rule).

Comment: @seanbreeden It is working fro me after adding website filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many products in your store then this is the efficient way. You may add website_id, custom_group_id in where class to be more specific.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalogrule_product');
$productIdList = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT product_id as product_id FROM '.$tableName.' WHERE rule_id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after adding website filter to the code suggested by seanbreeden.

```
$catalog_rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(1);  // Rule ID
$catalog_rule->addWebsiteFilter('1');
$skus = $catalog_rule->getMatchingProductIds();

var_dump($skus);
```