# How can I get Catalog price rules for a custom source model?

Tags: magento

I can't find a way to get catalog price rules in magento to show up.

I tried:

```
Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()
```

but I get nothing.

Comment: Here are similar solved threads:

 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454298/retrieve-all-product-ids-associated-with-a-catalog-price-rule-in-magento
 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998511/magento-need-to-get-product-collection-on-catalog-price-rule-applied

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')
            ->setValidationFilter($websiteId, $customerGroupId, $couponCode) //if needed
            ->load();
```